# Не работает скрипт на iPhone 4/6

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Есть корзина на jQuery (`wicart`). Везде работает нормально, даже на древних ИЕ.

Но не добавляет товар в корзину на iPhone 4 и 6. На остальных - все в порядке, на iPad'ах - тоже. К сожалению, нет возможности лично протестировать в виду отсутствия оных. На эмуляторах всё работает.

Добавление товара в корзину:

```
<a href="/basket/"
        onclick="cart.addToCart(this,'/playhouses/amsterdam/','Домик Амстердам',49000)"
        style="text-decoration:none" class="btn pink l">В&nbsp;корзину</a>
```

Инициализация корзины:

```
this.init = function(widjetID, config)
{
    this.CONFIG = config || {};
    try
    {
        this.DATA = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(widjetID));
        if ($.isEmptyObject(this.DATA))
        {
            this.DATA = {};
        }   
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        this.DATA = {};
        //сonsole.log("TRY - BED");
    }
    try
    {
        this.IDS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(widjetID + "_ids"));
        if ($.isEmptyObject(this.IDS))
        {
            this.IDS = [];
        }   
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        this.IDS = [];
    }   
    this.cardID = widjetID; 
    $("body").append("<div class='bird' id='" + widjetID + "_bird'></div>");    
    this.widjetObj = $("#" + widjetID);
    this.widjetPos = this.widjetObj.position(); 

    if ($.isEmptyObject(this.DATA))
    {
        this.widjetObj.html("Корзина пуста");
        $('#basket_empty').html('<h1>Ваша корзина пуста</h1>');
        $('#cart_form').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#basket_empty').html('<h1>Ваши покупки</h1>');
        this.reCalc();  
        this.renderBasketTable();
    }   
}
```

Сам скрипт добавления:

```
this.addToCart = function(curObj, id, name, price, href)
{
    id = ($.isNumeric(id)) ? "ID" + id.toString() : id;
    var goodieLine = { "id": id, "name": name, "price": price, "num": 1, "url": id };
    if ($.isEmptyObject(this.DATA))
    {
        this.DATA[id] = goodieLine; 
        this.IDS.push(id);
    }
    else
        for (var idkey in this.DATA) 
        {
            if ($.inArray(id, this.IDS) === -1)
            {
                this.DATA[id] = goodieLine;
                this.IDS.push(id)

            }
            else if (idkey == id)
            {
                this.DATA[idkey].num += 1;
            }
        }
    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID, JSON.stringify(this.DATA));
    localStorage.setItem(this.cardID + "_ids", JSON.stringify(this.IDS));
    this.reCalc();
    this.renderBasketTable();
}
```

Comment: Не заметил каких-либо особых проблем в коде (и неудивительно - он ведь работает почти везде). Единственное, что можно посоветовать, - раздобыть проблемное устройство и протестировать на нём, выявив ошибку.

Comment: как вариант попробовать без this. возможно на этих айфонах js принудительно заворачивается в use strict , а нём есть ограничения на this . хотя честно скажу весь код глубоко не смотрел , просто первое что пришло в голову. ps : дайте ссылку на сайт может гляну на своих i девайсах есть ли проблема или нет, и тут надо смотреть не на модель устройства ,а на IOS

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, авось выгорит)
Вот ссылка на сайт: http://www.moydvor.com/